# How to pass an object of an interface and some other type to functional component in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

Let's say I have an interface

```
interface Setting {
    desc: string,
    title: string,
    value: string | number | boolean | number[] | float,
    value_type: "string" | "integer" | "bool" | "list" | "float"
}
```

And a functional component that accepts two arguments

```
const SettingsOption = ({ ...option }: Setting, test: string): JSX.Element => {return (...)}
```

Such function signature seems fine to TypeScript compiler.

Next, I try to call the component using `<SettingsOption {...option} test=""/>` but it says

```
type '{ test: string; desc: string; title: string; value: string | number | boolean | number[]; value_type: "string" | "float" | "integer" | "bool" | "list"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Setting'.
  Property 'test' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Setting'.ts(2322)
```

My question: is there a way to call such component with passing all necessary information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must notice to some points.

1. In React functional components, first parameter is component props and second is [**Forwarding refs to DOM components**](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components).
2. All properties you pass in JSX element will receive as **`porps`** in component.

So you can't have `test` for second parameter. Also if you use `test` as properties in JSX element, `SettingsOption` will get it in props. Because of this you get that error.

```
interface Setting {
    desc: string,
    title: string,
    test: string;
    value: string | number | boolean | number[] | float,
    value_type: "string" | "integer" | "bool" | "list" | "float"
}
```

```
const SettingsOption = ({ ...option }: Setting): JSX.Element => {return (...)}
```

Alternatively instead of using the functional component as element, you can call it as function and pass all necessary arguments:

```
return (
    <div>
        {SettingsOption(option, "test")}
    </div>
)
```

But this approach may cause to rise `Rendered more times than during previous render` if your component uses hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because first param is props object and the second param is reference for React.forwardRef API. But you can use rest operator, example:

```js
interface Setting {
    desc: string,
    title: string,
    value: string | number | boolean | number[] | float,
    value_type: "string" | "integer" | "bool" | "list" | "float",
    test: string
}
const SettingsOption = ({test, ...option }: Setting): JSX.Element => {return (...)}
```